# How to "import" formula from another sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a document with 2 sheets in it.

For example, "Sheet 1" is

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =A1+A3 |
| 2 | =A2+A3 |
| 3 |  |

And I have "Sheet 2", which is

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| X | Y |
| Z | W |
| 4 |  |

Where instead of "X, Y, Z, W" I want to *import* formulas (preferably all of them at once)  from "Sheet 1", so if I change formula in "Sheet 1" it automatically changes formula in "Sheet 2".

How to implement that? I was trying "ARRAYFORMULA" and "IMPORTRANGE" but they don't locally import formulas.

Comment: I understand that you want to import the formula not the result of it right? Also are you willing to use Apps Script, with Google Sheet formulas is not possible. Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output, whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: @LorenaGomez I am not using Apps Script, only standard formulas and functions of g.sheets. 
And exactly, I just want to make a "link" to formula from one sheet to another, and evaluate it separately.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to retrieve formulas of a cell with Google Sheet formulas, it is a product limitation for Google Sheets. You can request this feature to be available through Google Sheets by going to a Google Sheet file, click on ‘Help’ > ‘Help Sheets improve’ and give a description of your request.